# Java JDK versions eclipse Blackboard 9.1 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: eclipse, java, blackboard

I have successfully implemented and deployed a hello world project adding a admin Example Admin Tool.
I did this after having to correct all version of JRE/JDK to 1.6 in 3 places in eclipse (project, ant, and general eclipse java setting).
Now I'm trying to compile a project given to us by an external contractor (which is working in .war format). I want to extend the project myself.
The project  has axis jars in it etc and references the blackboard jars and although it compiles in eclipse,  upon deployment to Bb and running it I get  get:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
Ive tried to compile in JDK 1.7 and I also get an error. It seems related to versions - which JDK version should i be using for Bb 9.1?
Can anyone shed any light?
full errors:
com/streaming/SearchManager

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/streaming/SearchManager
    at org.apache.jsp.helix.resultsList_jsp._jspService(resultsList_jsp.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1109.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at blackboard.platform.servlet.B2ContextFilter.doFilter(B2ContextFilter.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at blackboard.platform.servlet.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at blackboard.platform.servlet.XssServletFilter.doFilter(XssServletFilter.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1111.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at blackboard.platform.servlet.RequestSessionFilter.doFilter(RequestSessionFilter.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:554)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:647)
    at blackboard.tomcat.valves.LoggingRemoteIpValve.invoke(LoggingRemoteIpValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close - this is a very specific question which is not to my mind programming related.  If you want to know what version of Java Bb 9.1 uses, I suggest you read its documentation rather than asking Stack Overflow.

Comment: before you do that can anyone just confirm my thoughts on the meaning of this error?

Comment: (i have a question on blackboard forums too - and their documentation links are broken hence not knowing this answer)

Comment: You're right that `UnsupportedVersionError` means that the JVM at runtime doesn't understand the version of the class it's being asked to load - almost certainly because it was compiled by a newer version of the JDK (e.g. 1.7-compiled code being passed to a 1.6 JRE).

Answer (score 0):

The version of the JDK running will vary depending on the local setup.  After Blackboard Learn 9.1 Service Pack 10 (the October 2012 release) systems should be running a version of JDK 1.7.  Prior that they are probably running under JDK1.6 though some are running under 1.7.  You should contact your local administrator to determine the path to the JDK and get the version used. The path to the JDK is stored in the bb-config.properies file.

The problem in your jsp file is probably that it is referencing a library in your webapps/WEB-INF/lib (local Building Block libraries) which is incompatible with the version of the JDK on the target Blackboard system.  It appears that your jsp is being compiled at runtime on the blackboard server and is failing because of this third party libraries compatibility. If you want to precompile the jsp in the war file you must use jspc as an ant task.